# Passing instance variables in table rows to modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my app, I have a table which shows a list of posts that users have made. In each row, there's a button that opens a modal, showing a list of users who have sent messages in response to that post. I'm having trouble passing the correct variables to a modal.

If I run the `@conversations` loop below, which I'm using to get the list of users, outside of the modal and in the row itself, it works. But when I try to use the loop inside the modal, it uses the `offer` from the first row instead of the `offer` for the row on which the button was clicked.

For example, if I have a list of offers with the following titles:

- This is the first offer.
- This is the second offer.
- This is the third offer.

The command `<% if reply.subject == offer.title %>`, which is run inside the modal, will use the first  `offer.title`, "This is the first offer.", even if I click the button in the third row. Because of this, the modal only works for the first row, and then shows the same users when opened from any other row.

```
<% @offers.each do |offer| %>
        <tr>



          <td><%= link_to offer.title, offer_path(offer) %></td>


            <%= button_to offer_path(offer),
                          :id => 'contacts', "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => '#showContactsModal',
                          :class => 'btn btn-success', :style => "border-radius: 0;" do %>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> View Users Who Contacted You
            <% end %>





            <div class="modal fade" id="showContactsModal">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                      Who contacted you about this offer?</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">

                    <% @conversations.each do |reply| %>
                        <% if reply.subject == offer.title %>
                            <%= reply.originator.name %>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->
          </td>
      </td>

   </tr>

<% end %>
```

How can I fix this so that the modal receives the correct variable for its row?

I've just noticed that in my `button_to`, I've provided the path to the offer show view, which is unnecessary, I just want it to show the modal. Should I be giving it a nil path or something?

Feel free to edit this question to make it more general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modal is being created multiple times within the offer loop with the same ID (`showContactsModal`). And the button you created only activates the first modal because it is calling that ID.

So your `data-target` in your `button_to` needs to be set to some unique value, such as:

```
<%= button_to offer_path(offer),
    :id => 'contacts', "data-toggle" => "modal", 
    'data-target' => '#showContactsModal_' + offer.id.to_s,
    :class => 'btn btn-success', :style => "border-radius: 0;" do %>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> View Users Who Contacted You
<% end %>
```

Then when creating your modal, set the ID attribute to match the `data-target`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<%= 'showContactsModal_%s' % [offer.id] %>">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

This way your JS knows which modal to show to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue might be due to some improper formatting in the code. Besides that the next thing on my mind is that since you aren't using unique IDs for each modal in each row (I believe that you wanted a modal belonging to each row) you aren't replacing the content correctly.

```
<% @offers.each do |offer| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to offer.title, offer_path(offer) %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= button_to offer_path(offer), :id => 'contacts', "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => '#showContactsModal_#{offer.id}', :class => 'btn btn-success', :style => "border-radius: 0;"%>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">View Users Who Contacted You</i>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="modal fade hide" id="showContactsModal_#{offer.id}">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Who contacted you about this offer?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <% @conversations.each do |reply| %>
                <% if reply.subject == offer.title %>
                  <%= reply.originator.name %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </td>
  </tr>

<% end %>
```